# Is fb:multi-friend-selector deprecated?

Tags: facebook, fbml, deprecated, xfbml

I have a page in my website to invite Facebook friends to use my website and the code is pretty standard stuff

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width: 755px;">  
 <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml>
        <fb:request-form ....
            <fb:req-choice />
         >
         </fb:request-form>
            <fb:multi-friend-selector .../>
     </fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

As far as what I understand, because I am including FB JS SDK, it interprets the XFBML tags and includes the appropriate html for the same (which is interpreted by the browser).

I hear that FBML is being deprecated. I am assuming that this will not affect the XFBML tags, rt? Can someone please confirm? I am confused because all these tags have been listed in FB documentation under Advanced Topics › Legacy FBML › fb:serverFbml.

I also have other tags in various other pages like `<fb:profile-pic>, <fb:name>, <fb:title>, <fb:iframe>, <fb:google-analytics>` Should I be migrating them to their HTML equivalent?

Is there some documentation on how to go about doing this? Any inputs is highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fb:multi-friend-selector` never had XFBML versions but only FBML which isn't the same since FBML only works in application canvas and only for apps that use FBML (not an iframe)

Cite from [FBML documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

> **We are deprecating FBML**. On **Jan 1, 2012:** FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. **June 1, 2012:** FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript) and [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

**Update:**
You still can use it with `FB.XFBML.parse` method of JavaScript SDK.

In your case looks like you should move `fb:multi-friend-selector` to be within `fb:request-form` (like it shown on [`fb:request-form` documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/).

But I strongly suggest using [`Requests Dialog`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) with JavaScript SDK instead of FBML tags

**Update 2:**
While not officially confirmed (yet) I'll allow myself to speculate on this a bit. Probably every FBML tags will be removed and `fb:serverFbml` will not be parsed by JS-SDK after **June 1, 2012**.
You can try to ask about this on Quora (with a big change to get response from one of officials

Comment: Thanks for the reply Juicy. But I see, fb:serverfbml listed here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ .  Is this the list of XFBML tags?

Comment: @SriramSubramanian you're right about `fb:serverFbml` it is supported with `FB.XFBML.parse` method of JavaScript SDK (which you still can use to render FBML). I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Also as explained before, fb:multi-friend-selector works fine for a FB logged in user (currently) in a page on my website (not a canvas page) which has the new FB JS (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) included.

Comment: Thanks again Juicy. Yes, the fb:multi-friend-selector is within the fb:request-form. I made a mistake when pasting the code here. So, will this stop working after June (I dont actually call a FB.XFBML.parse explicitly) or is it that it will still work? Also, what about the other FBML tags listed in my post?

Comment: I was reading thru the documentation  for Requests Dialog that you suggested and it has this "If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will be sent to the canvas URL of the application that sent the request". I want the user to be redirected to my website and not the canvas page. This is possible currently by using <fb:req-choice url="http://mywebsite"/>